C++ Eigen svd.singularValues() returns only the nonzero ones. How do I get the zero ones as well?
I'm trying to compute the nullspace of a matrix (in this case, a matrix with one row, i.e. a vector).
To do so I compute its SVD using the Eigen::JacobiSvd class (Edit: passing ComputeFullV as a parameter). It has a function, singularValues that returns a vector with the singular values of the matrix.
EDIT: I specifically want an orthonormal basis, which SVD guarantees by default while other sorts of decompositions don't necessarily do.
The problem is that it only returns the nonzero values, and I'm interested in the zero values (and which singular vectors correspond to them) to compute a nullspace. Is there a way to get the zero values as well, in order to find their corresponding columns?
I searched Eigen's documentation on the JacobiSvd class for more info on its member function but couldn't find any. Was I looking at the wrong place?
Edit 2: This is the function that I'm using:
Eigen::MatrixXd nullspace(const Eigen::MatrixXd& mat, double tol = 1e-5) {
// Perform SVD
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd> svd(mat, Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);

// Get the singular values
Eigen::VectorXd singularValues = svd.singularValues();
// debug
cout << "size of singular values array" << singularValues.size() << endl;
cout << singularValues.transpose() << endl;

// Determine the dimension of the nullspace
int nullity = (singularValues.array() < tol).count();

// Get the matrix V from the decomposition
Eigen::MatrixXd V = svd.matrixV();

// Extract the basis vectors for the nullspace
Eigen::MatrixXd ns = V.rightCols(nullity);

// If nullity is 1, return the vector instead of a matrix
if (nullity == 1) {
    return ns.col(0); // Return the first column as a vector
}

// Return the basis vectors of the nullspace
return ns;

with the input 1x3 matrix (1, 1, 1).

might be a bad idea, but your null space is of dimension D-1, provided your input vector is not null. Then may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process can be used (build a base using the input vector as a base vector, then you can orthogonalize the rest)

This question is similar to: How to compute basis of nullspace with Eigen library?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

the 'singularValues' function indeed returns only the non-zero singular values, what you can do is loop through all the matrix before and change all values less than (1e-10) to a small number also could be (1e-10;), then you have something almost zero, you can use it, but I don't think that you can do it using 'Eigen::JacobiSvd'

btw, I think that what your looking for are the D-1 first columns of svd.matrixV() where svd is the JacobiSvd object (The m first columns of V are the right singular vectors of the matrix being decomposed. from https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SVDBase.html)

@Oersted in the case where the matrix is of rank 1 it just means every column but the first, correct?

I'm unsure, it depends on the implementation choice (it's not a mathematical rule). You can just test but looking closely at the doc, I think you may be right (non-null singular values would be on the left of S matrix in Eigen implementation).

@Orested can I just take the diagonal of S directly, or is it not actually computed (and only the nonzero singular values are saved)?

You need to pass ComputeFullV to get the basis vectors of the null space. It is documented in the first paragraphs of JacobiSVD.

@chtz I did, will edit accordingly

@RonTubman Yes, please provide a [mre] including which Eigen version you are using and what input matrix you are testing with.

For an n x m matrix svd.singularValues() will never return a vector larger than min(n, m). To compute nullity just check how many values are above tol (or use svd.rank() and compute m-rank.

N.B. Is there a reason that for (nullity == 1) you want to return the leftmost vector instead of the rightmost? Also, there is no benefit in returning "as a vector", since your function converts it into a MatrixXd anyways.
